# How to add values into a nested structure which has two pointers inside in C++

Tags: c++, structure, doubly-linked-list

```
struct stable_item 
{
    char* name;
    char* scope;
    int permission;
};

struct stable 
{
    stable_item* item;
    stable * next;
    stable * prev;
};

stable* head;
//structures created

stable *GetNewNode() {
    stable *newNode = new stable();
    newNode->item;
    newNode->next = NULL;
    newNode->prev = NULL;
    return newNode;
};

void insert_stable()
{
    stable *newNode = GetNewNode();
    if (head == NULL) {
       head = newNode;
       return;
    }
    head->prev = newNode;
    newNode->next = head;
    head = newNode;
}

void update_item()
{
  struct stable_item *newItem = (struct stable_item*)malloc(sizeof(struct stable_item));
  head->item->permission;
  head->item->name == NULL;
  head->item->scope = NULL;
};
```

I am having trouble inserting a value into a nested structure in C++.

I am going to update the information of **name, scope, and permission** in **struct stable_item**. But since there is a pointer item within another structure, which is **stable**, I am currently confused the way of realizing this task. Maybe I need to declare an object of **struct stable_item** first?

Could anyone help me check on what would be the possible improvements?

Comment: The line `newNode->item;` does nothing at all. You may want to create classes and use oop correctly to have less confusing code ?

Comment: `head->item->name == x;` That's not exactly correct.

Comment: You are creating a home-made *doubly linked-list* class and not some random nested structure that has not been seen before.  Either search the thousands of links available on *doubly linked list* creation, or simply use `std::list`.

Comment: **Don't cast `malloc`** -> `struct stable_item *newItem = malloc(sizeof(struct 
  stable_item));`

Comment: Note that `struct XXX { … };` needs a semicolon at the end, but a function definition does not need a semicolon at the end.  (In fact, the semicolon represents an empty declaration.)  When you're coding in C++, you should not be using `malloc()`.  Indeed, in modern C++, you should seldom need to use `new` even.  Both of them risk memory leaks and other problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply allocate some memory for `newNode->item`, as shown below.

```cpp
  stable *GetNewNode(){
      stable *newNode = new stable();
-->   newNode->item = new stable_item(); // Do this as you've done above
>     newNode->item->name = NULL;
>     newNode->item->scope = NULL;
>     newNode->item->permission = 0;
      newNode->next = NULL;
      newNode->prev = NULL;
      return newNode;
  }
```

```cpp
  void update_item(int perm, const char* name, const char* scope){
>     struct stable_item *newItem = new stable_item();
>     head->item->permission = perm;
>     head->item->name = new char[1+strlen(name)];
>     strcpy(head->item->name, name);
>     head->item->scope = new char[1+strlen(scope)];
>     strcpy(head->item->scope, scope);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your editing. But in void update_item( ) { .......}, as you have assigned " new char[1+strlen(name)] " to " head->item->name ", then why did you use  " strcpy(head->item->name, name); "? Is there any reason?

Comment: To copy data in case the original is out of its life span (or gets destroyed.

Comment: @hereticalcoral Think what would happen with `update_item(0, "aaa", "bbb");`. As soon as the function returns the strings you've supplied gets invalidated. Pointing to them directly is very dangerous.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks a lot!